# SoapUI Installation Error - com.install4j

Tags: soapui

I am having this issue where I am trying to install SoapUI and I just cannot get it right.

I have been through MANY posts, with "solutions", but they either do not explain exactly what is required to resolve the issue OR the issue is not in the same context as what mine is OR the issue is unresolved.

So here's what happens:

1. Execute the SoapUI.exe file (as admin or non-admin) - In my case, it's SoapUI_5.5.exe
2. Installation window for SoapUI comes up and show's a progress bar
3. The installation window closes and in the same directory as the exe file, I get two log file outputs

The log files are named:

- install4jError.log
- error.log

The contents of the files are massive, so I will provide snippets:

**install4jError.log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
```

**error.log**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Continuing ...
An error occurred:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
Error log: C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\SoapUI (x64) (5.5.0)\install4jError4630268005895903797.log
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
```

I'm not sure what the issue is or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually figured out how to get the install done..

1. Put the exe file in the following location: **c:\Temp\SoapUI_5-5-0.exe**
2. Open a CMD window and navigate to this location by typing the following command: ***cd c:\Temp***
3. Type the following two commands in the CMD window:

*Commands:*

- **set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=**
- **set _JAVA_OPTIONS=**

After this:

4. Execute the Soap install file via the CMD window simply by typing in the name of the execution file: **SoapUI_5-5-0.exe**

The install went perfectly and I am still not sure why or what the reason is behind the fix.

Comment: Just wanted to add I had to Google this solution 6 months later because I came across the same problem on a new install again. Not sure why this is the case.